# Custom authentication : Odata services

Tags: odata

Do you know of a way for me to create a customer authentication in Odata services? I don't want to use the default ASP.NET membership model and NetworkCredential.

---

I have already referred section : authentication-part-6-custom-basic-authentication.aspx. But i am not able to debug Httpmodule i.e Init() of Httpmodule

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what version of IIS you are deploying/testing in.

I found that when using IIS version less than 7, your new HttpModule should be declared in System.web/HttpModules tag. In version 7 and higher, it should be in the System.webserver/Modules tag.

Within IIS, enable just anonymous authentication.